# Trying to Display Content of CK Editor on Same View in a Different DIV

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, textarea, view

I have created the following CK Editor using the online source

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">

    <h2>CK EDITOR CONSOLE</h2>

    @Html.TextArea("Explanation")

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/ckfinder/ckfinder.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'];
      if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
      CKEDITOR.replace('Explanation', {
        enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
      });
      CKFinder.setupCKEditor(null, '@Url.Content("~/ckfinder/")');
    </script>

    <form method="post" action="">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text, new { id = "Explanation" })
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now I would like to display the content I input (Text/Images) in a separate Area on the same View on button click Submit.

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: You mean you want some sort of preview of everything you entered? Why do you want to submit?, you could pass the html to a certain div with jquery without submitting to server...

Comment: Yes and how do I pass that html to a certain div please from my CKEditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an empty div where the preview will be:

```
<div id="explanation-preview"></div>
```

Add a button to generate preview, that does not submit the form, for instance:

```
<button type="button" id="preview">Click me to preview!</button>
```

From jquery, after your ckeditor was declared, capture button click and pass contents from the editor to the div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'];

    // ...

    $('#preview').on('click', function() {
        $('#explanation-preview').html(editor.getData());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like nothing is happening Zed.... The button is not even being announced on de-bug

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console? (F12). Also, do you have included [jquery](https://jquery.com/download/)? If you add `console.log('test');` inside `#preview` button click handler, does get printed at browser console when you click it?

Comment: Zed, unfortunately I am a beginner and I am not following, what I have done is put the Code you gave me after the <script> of where I call the ckeditor, then I created a Div where I put the button in.

Comment: I also tried to debugg the solution and placed a debugg point at the script of the on click function of the preview button yet it is not even being toggled...